# How do I estimate a cube corner from a projected square?

Tags: computer-vision, geometry

I've got the coordinates of a square's corners projected onto an image. I want to know where I'd find the corners of a cube if they were projected onto the image.

More specifically, assuming a square with sides of length 1.  It's at the origin with coordinates (x, y, z) of (0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (1, 1, 0). I know the corresponding projected locations (u, v) for those square corners. how do I find the (u, v) for the (x, y, z) point (0, 0, 1) ?

I'm really just looking for an equations that will give u<sub>001</sub> and v<sub>001</sub> in terms of the scalar values:

- u<sub>000</sub> v<sub>000</sub>
- u<sub>100</sub> v<sub>100</sub>
- u<sub>010</sub> v<sub>010</sub>
- u<sub>110</sub> v<sub>110</sub>

I think the transformation matrix in homogenous coordinates from `(x, y, z, 1)` to `(u, v, w)` will look like:

```
 a b c d 
 e f g h 
 i j k 1
```

But I can't figure out how to find `c`, `g`, or `k` without a z point.

---

Doing some algebra:

```
d = u_00  
h = v_00

a = u_10 * (i+1) - u_00  
b = u_01 * (j+1) - u_00  
e = v_10 * (i+1) - v_00  
f = v_01 * (j+1) - v_00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perspective projection, 4 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925569/perspective-projection-4-points)

Comment: What plane are you projecting on?